# How to send notification to user when new version is available the application is built on by using PhoneGap Framework?

Tags: android, cordova

I am making new version of my application. I want to give a notification to the users when the new version of app is available automatically. I don't know how to do this. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it your application is a hybrid Application build by using PhoneGap.

Comment: i'm using phonegap to develop this app.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Configure app]

Ok.For this when you build your application using `PhoneGap` Build Tool.You have to set `Hydration mode` on before building your application.When you set the `Hydration Mode` application will be automatically notified.For this,

Go : `apps->settings->select "enable Hydration" mode -> save.`

Again build your application with this settings.Run in your mobile devices.Again build app using `PhoneGap` Build.Your application will be automatically notified of the new version.

You can see the screenshot i have uploaded here.

Comment: Does it work now? I know its about 3 years old post.